# Would it be legally possible to release a new Lord of the Rings/The Hobbit movie series, which instead of butchering the books actually honors them?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, copyright

**Did the Tolkien estate sell the movie rights to Hollywood, or could they still allow somebody else to make an actual LOTR/Hobbit movie series?**

That is, one which actually follows the books' story instead of butchering them completely and inventing all kinds of nonsense?

After recently re-reading them, then watching the existing movies, I felt a deep sadness not just because of the miserable viewing experience, but the thought that the big masses of people have no idea what LOTR/Hobbit are actually about, as they have only seen those ridiculous movies.

I also disagree violently with those who defend the LOTR movies but are negative toward the Hobbit ones. I find both to be equally nonsensical and completely detached from the source material.

Almost every scene in those existing movies bore me out of my mind, and it's not because they are "slow". They certainly aren't. They are just an endless series of ridiculous stunts, shaky cameras and physics-defying nonsense, and even the calm scenes manage to be completely uninteresting due to how dumbed down the story and dialogue is.

I want to see real LOTR/Hobbit movies in my lifetime. Could it be done legally?

Comment: I don't think it is nice to do such a comprehensive removal without author's permission. That is why I rolled back.

Comment: @C.Koca I think it’s preferable not to have a massive rant that only detracts from the question. Some authorial intent is fine but long rambling paragraphs of rant that only detract, and likely draw downvoted, no, preferable to leave that out.

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to add a very small "TL;DR" section on top and then elaborate on your view.

Comment: @C.Koca - As things stand it's just a rant. If OP doesn't remove it themselves, it'll get closed anyway.

Comment: Christopher Tolkien has the same view as you and the answer is no, almost certainly not until they enter the public domain in 2044 or thereabouts.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot It is not upto us.

Comment: I think the answer can be obtained by entering `Lord of the Rings rights` into Google.

Comment: @C.Koca of course it’s not _entirely_ up to us but the whole point of SE is that it’s not _entirely_ up to the OP either. Beat to make a readable and answerable question than a rant that’ll only end up closed.

Comment: @C.Koca In any case, they're an unregistered user, so in my experience, they're more likely to never visit the site again than they are to decide on whether we should leave the question in its original state.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot It feels like a meta discussion to me. Go ahead with the deletion if you want I won't roll back again, but please also make a meta post, where we can discuss this for future occurences.

Comment: @F1Krazy Of course they won't if we are this hostile to newcomers, in spite of the "new contributor" warning.

Comment: @C.Koca I was about to edit my comment. I didn't mean that they'd see this discussion and be scared off by it, although that is a possibility. But what I think is much more likely (and what I meant originally) is that they've posted this, then immediately disappeared, and they have no idea that this debate is even occurring.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, when someone buys the "movie rights" to a work, it's an exclusive deal, though often limited to a set period of time.

So, to do something like this, one would need the cooperation of whoever currently owns those rights. If they are currently still in the hands of Jackson et al, then there's probably no path forward (at least for now). If/when the rights revert back to the estate, then the heirs will want to make a profit and they may or may not care about "artistic integrity" or anything else that gets in the way of making the profit. They also will want to deal with someone who can show that they have the resources to actually complete the project and generate that profit.

TLDR - sure, anything's possible if you're willing to spend enough money. In this case, you're probably talking hundreds of millions of dollars.

I think it's also relevant to bring up "a tale of two movies", namely [The Fountainhead](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0041386/) and [Atlas Shrugged (Part 1)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0480239/). Same author, two very different results.

Comment: given the estate has sold some rights to Amazon, who has since hired nudity consultants for their upcoming show (true story)...artistic integrity and adhering to the spirit of Tolkien seem to be now entirely off the table

Comment: I now have a new career goal.

Comment: "No no no I keep telling you pointy ears pointy nipples"

Comment: @NKCampbell they sold off different rights to Amazon.